# Caliburn.Micro NuGet Install Fails on Portable Class Library Project

Tags: xamarin, nuget, caliburn.micro, portable-class-library

I am attempting to instal the Caliburn.Micro-Contrib NuGet package into an empty PCL project in VS 2013 Professional.

I get the following error from NuGet when attempting to install the package:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Caliburn.Micro (≥ 1.3.1)'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'.
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro-Contrib 1.0.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro-Contrib 1.0.2'.
Adding 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1' to ClassLibrary2.
Uninstalling 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net40+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

What is the cause of the problem and how can I fix this?

Note the package installs successfully for a standard class project but not for PCL projects. The PCL is intended to be a Xamarin Android and iOS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that [Caliburn.Micro Contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro-Contrib/) has a PCL Compatible package.  It also depends on the full (not PCL) version of Caliburn Micro.  Also note that it appears that Xamarin support is only available in the pre-release beta of Caliburn Micro.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know the name and version of the CM NuGet package I should use in a Caliburn.Micro Xamarin project (PCL that has an Android and iOS project)?

Comment: Edit for above comment. Looks like you suggested a package in my other question - maybe thats the package I am looking for?